# How to change the directory/file path of a file being served by Firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am currently hosting a static website through Firebase, but the one file being served (`index.html`) exists in my Mac computer's Public folder. Since I would like to serve other files, I want to move the index to a project folder that will contain future linked files (e.g. `/public/my-project/index.html`).

How would I go about updating the file path/directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your project directory (the directory in which you run `firebase deploy` or `firebase deploy --only hosting`), open or create `firebase.json` and make sure it points to the correct public folder.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public"
  }
}
```

This is a relative path. If your project and your `firebase.json` are located in `/projects/my-project`, this will deploy everything in `/projects/my-project/public`.

**All of this is set up automatically** if you initialize your Firebase project with `firebase init`.

Since your project may contain lots of files that aren't supposed to be deployed (readme, node_modules, build scripts etc.), I'd recommend having a `public` folder inside the project folder, like described above. (You can, however, ignore files with the `ignore` option, but you'd like to keep this list of ignored files manageable.)

If you really don't want a `public` folder inside your project, you may try pointing to the current folder from your `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "."
  }
}
```

More information about hosting configuration: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config

Comment: Thanks for the response. Which folder would I put the firebase.json file in? And how can I change the file path to begin with? Right now it is just set to `/public/`, but I want to create a folder inside `/public/` for this project specifically and change the file path to go to that folder. In other words, `/public/my-project/index.html` would be the instructions instead of `/public/index.html`

Comment: Put `firebase.json` in your project's root. Since your project may contain lots of files that aren't supposed to be deployed (readme, node_modules, build scripts etc.), I'd recommend creating a `public` folder inside the project folder, like `/public/my-project/public/index.html`. Your `firebase.json` (located at `public/my-project/firebase.json` should then point to this `public` folder, like `{ hosting: { "public": "public" } }`.

Comment: If you really don't want a `public` folder inside your project, you may try pointing to the current folder from your `firebase.json`, like `{ hosting: { "public": "." } }`

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. This wasn't quite the answer I was looking for, but you gave me a really solid tip here that I probably would have overlooked if I hadn't asked here. Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad to hear it! I incidentally added some info about `firebase init` to my answer right before I saw your own new answer (which is great!) :)

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally stumbled across the answer while tweaking my settings in Terminal, it was a lot simpler than I expected. For future reference to anyone who sees this,

1. Open Terminal, and enter `firebase init` ([assuming you have node.js and firebase already installed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started)).
2. Use your arrows keys to navigate down to the `○ Hosting` option, press your spacebar to select, and `Return/Enter` key to proceed.
3. The question "**What do you want to use as your public directory?**" will prompt. Type your desired file path (i.e. `public/my-project/public`) and enter.
4. The question "**Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)?**" This is your choice and depends on your platform.
5. If a file named `index.html` already exists in that location, it will ask if you want to overwrite it and create a new one. Most likely, you will want to keep the existing index you have -- if this is the case, type `n`.

Make sure to also follow @nicoqh's valuable advice and differentiate between your public and private folders so that not all of your files end up getting deployed by Firebase.